# Cocoa: Close the app when a HUD panel is closed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspanel

I need to close the entire app when the user click on a Panel close button,
I tried:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
    return YES;
}
```

but it closes the app also from file-selector panels.

Thank you in advance.
L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications can't be closed, only quit. Only windows can be closed, not applications.

If you want to quit the application when only a specific window is closed, be that window's delegate and respond to [the `windowWillClose:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose%3a) by [telling the application to terminate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate%3a).

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I Solved adding
 `- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSApp terminate:nil]; 
}` and setting App Delegate as delegate in Outlets.